# Prove that $\sum \leq \frac{3n-2}{2n-1}$

Tags: inequality, induction

For every $n\in N$, we have:$$a_{n}=\frac{1}{1^{2}}+\frac{1}{2^{2}}+\frac{1}{3^{2}}+...+\frac{1}{n^{2}}$$
Then let $\sum$ be: $$\sum =\frac{1}{a_{1}^{2}}+\frac{1}{4a_{2}^{2}}+\frac{1}{9a_{3}^{2}}+...+\frac{1}{n^{2}a_{n}^{2}}$$
Prove that $\sum \leq \frac{3n-2}{2n-1}$, $\vee n\in N,n\neq 0$
My attempts:

First I tried using $\frac{1}{n^{2}}<\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}$ and then I found $a_{n}< 2-\frac{1}{n},\vee   n>1$,  with $a_{1}=1$
$a_{2}< 2-\frac{1}{2}$ etc. 
But then I arrived at $\sum \geq 1^{2}+3^{2}+...+(2n-1)^{2}$, but I need $\sum$ lower than something, not grater.

Then I found that $\frac{1}{n^{2}}>\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ , and I arrived at $a_{n}>\frac{n}{n+1}$, but in this case 4,9,..,n^2 don't simplify. Also I found that $a_{n}<\frac{4n}{2n+1},\vee   n\geq 1$(with induction) but $a_{n}$ has to be greater than something, so that $\frac{1}{a_{n}}$ and $\sum$ to be lower.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It was asked recently (2 or 3 weeks ago).

Comment: thank you very much, i searched the question,but i haven't found that

Comment: ok, thank you..

Comment: I'm confused. What has your question to do with `linear-algebra`?

Comment: sorry, i edited it now